# Move blob field into new table (id, blob), and replace it with id from new table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a BLOB field that contains images of 1-2 MBs. I want to create a new table that has only 2 fields - a primary key with a reference ID and the BLOB, then replace the field that holds the BLOB with a field that holds the reference ID for the same BLOB in the new table.

I don't know SQL very well, I'm not even sure if this is possible using only SQL. Or do I need to make a C++/Python program to do it?

Note: I'm using SQLite for the database, and since they don't enforce types for the fields, I don't even need to create a new field, I can just replace the BLOB with the ID.

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy all blobs to the other table, and update the old field with the ID of the new row.
The latter is possible with [last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid), but only for a single row, so you have to use a mechanism that does the inserts and updates step by step.

This can be done with a trigger (and a dummy view, so that the UPDATE that triggers the copying does not actually update a table):

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Blob);

CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW OldTable_view AS
SELECT * FROM OldTable;

CREATE TEMPORARY TRIGGER move_blob
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON OldTable_view
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO NewTable(Blob)
    SELECT Blob FROM OldTable WHERE ID = OLD.ID;

    UPDATE OldTable
    SET Blob = last_insert_rowid()
    WHERE ID = OLD.ID;
END;

UPDATE OldTable_view SET ID = ID;

DROP VIEW OldTable_view;
```

Comment: I tried to use the code you posted, but I can't make it work. I tried using a test table where the blob column has strings instead - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c29e7/1. Right now it gives me `could not prepare statement (1 near "ID": syntax error)`.

Comment: The new table must have an [autoincrementing ID](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). `ID` is whatever primary key the old table uses.